# WPF Crystal Reports: Detect opening Subreport

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I have a application with crystal reports wpf control. My application shows the current page number and the last page number of the report. This should also work for subreports.
Is there any event which tells me, when a subreport is opened?

Comment: but what you want with supreport. please explain

Comment: what i want is two things: 1. how to detect if a subreport is opened, 2. how to geht the current and last page number of the subreport

Comment: that does not controlled by us. and still not understand why you want open and close of sub report. do you need that page number to print with 1 when subreport open ?

Comment: i have my own wpf controls to interact with a report, i don't use the built in toolbar and stuff... in order to this i have a textbox which shows the first page number and a textblock which shows the last number of the report... when clicking on a value in the report, a subreport gets opened...to update the page numbers i have to know when a subreport is openend, but i think there is no event or something which tells me when its opened...

Comment: This means you want to create a whole new crystal report software indirectely. that not possible to use our custom control and its event map with crystal report. Check this link may be helpfull - https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Paging-in-Crystal-Reports-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx